# How do I automatically load a bunch of JS/CSS from sites/all/libraries without hook_library?

Tags: hooks, theming

My question is simple.

Is there a straightforward method to load a library e.g. ibeginshare (it contains 2 css, an images folder and 1 js) which I copied in `sites/all/libraries` to use it in my module?

I have created a module that implements hook_block_info and hook_block_view and I want to load this library in its hook_init.

Is it mandatory to use hook_library and define there everysingle file then call it via drupal_add_library? I am confused. What if I have dozens of js/css files ? What if I don't want necessarly to share the library with other modules?

NOTE
I managed to load the file like this:

**METHOD 1**

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/ibeginshare/share.js');
}
```

I would like a more elegant way so I tried:

**METHOD 2**

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  drupal_add_library('MYMODULE', 'ibeginshare');

}

/**
 * Implements hook_library().
 * @return string
 */
function MYMODULE_library() {
  $libraries['ibeginshare'] = array(
    'title' => 'ibeginshare',
    'website' => '',
    'version' => '1.2',
    'js' => array(
      'sites/all/libraries/ibeginshare/share.js' => array(),
    ),
    'css' => array(
      'sites/all/libraries/ibeginshare/share.css' => array(),
    ),
     'css' => array(
      'sites/all/libraries/ibeginshare/share-print.css' => array(),
    ),
  );

  return $libraries;
}
```

this loads all libraries but the plugin doesn't initialize. I wonder why.
I think will work if I add a weight property in the hook_library but anything I tried didn't work.

Comment: Seems you want these js and css files loaded on every page, if this is the case, I would probably do it from your module's .info file using scripts[] and stylesheets[all][]. I can't help you with the HOOK_library problem though, I've never used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on Drupal 7, `drupal_add_library()` will do just that for you. From the [function's API page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7):

> Adds multiple JavaScript or CSS files at the same time.
>
> A library defines a set of JavaScript and/or CSS files, optionally
>   using settings, and optionally requiring another library. For example,
>   a library can be a jQuery plugin, a JavaScript framework, or a CSS
>   framework. This function allows modules to load a library
>   defined/shipped by itself or a depending module, without having to add
>   all files of the library separately. Each library is only loaded once.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7

Note that you first need to define and register the library with [`hook_library()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_library/7).

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_library/7

Comment: But as I understand drupal_add_library($module, $name) needs a module name as argument which means it needs a manual implementation of hook_library in a module where you manually type all your js/css paths. There is no automatic scanning of libraries/mylibrary folder

Comment: That is correct - or is at least my understanding too. (You need to define the contents of the library "manually" with `hook_library` first). I must have missed the part of your question ("Is it mandatory to use hook_library... ?"). So a simpler answer would be, "As far as I know, yes".